# 301 redirect for wordpress permalink

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

on `.httaccess`, we use like this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food/(.*)$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/$1
```

It works well. but we have a problem with 1 old link. we used to have a multi-site and the name is "food". it was changed to "food-for-healthy". Therefore we have changed like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food/(.*)$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/$1
```

and as you know, `http//:domain.com/food/` and `http//:domain.com/food` are the same.

The problem is http//:domain.com/food which needs to go to http//:domain.com/food-for-healty/

I have tried several things but my attempts produce a redirect error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /food http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy
```

this gets a redirect error. how can I change it to work properly?

I have tried this..

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food/?(.*)$ http//:domain.com/food-for-healthy/$1
```

but
it comes with a redirect error and goes to

```
http:/:domain.com/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-h‌​ealthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/food-for-healthy/...
```

Comment: You need to be exact about the values that have worked and not worked for you. Neither `http:/:` nor `http//:` are valid ways to start a URL (where as `http://` is).

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason I can see why `RedirectMatch` is required since you're doing a simple redirect from one place to another and aren't dealing with additional query string values or sub-pages (that you've said).

```
Redirect permanent /food/ http://domain.com/food-for-healthy/
```